# How do I create a visualization of a SQL Server database without db_owner privileges?

Tags: sql-server, uml, data-modeling, database-schema

`Database diagrams` in SQL Server Management Studio looked promising, but I need `db_owner` privileges! I only want to temporarily see a diagram of a complicated with 5-10 tables.

Any alternative thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Ask for permission from the db owner.

Comment: It's a production, high-volume server, so I probably don't want or need any privileges beyond the read-only I currently have. 

I can read all of the schema, so I don't see why additional privileges are necessary to build the diagram.